# Can someone tell me how to make this checksum work? Debugging has led me to function luhn_even2 to be the issue

Tags: python-3.x, nested, data-conversion, luhn

```
x = 4000000000000000
y = 4000000000001000

def luhn_odd(j):
    j = str(j)
    j = list(j)
    sum_odd = 0
    k = 0
    for i in j:  #For loop to get the sum of odd indices
        i = j[k] #iterator attached to index
        if k%2 != 0:
            sum_odd = sum_odd + int(i)
        k += 1  
    return sum_odd 

def luhn_even1(m):
m = str(m)
m = list(m)
sum_even1 = 0
r_sum1 = 0
n = 0
for i in m:
    i = m[n]
    if n%2 == 0:
        sub_even1 = int(i)
        sub_even1 *= 2
        if sub_even1 < 9:
            r_sum1 = r_sum1 + sub_even1
        else:
            pass
    n += 1  
return r_sum1 

def luhn_even2(a):
a = str(a)
a = list(a)
b = 0
c = 0
sum_even3 = 0
for i in a:
    i = a[b]
    if b%2 == 0:
        sum_even2 = int(i) * 2
        if sum_even2 >= 10:
            for j in sum_even2:
                j = sum_even2[c]
                sum_even3 = sum_even3 + int(j)
                c += 1
    b += 1
    return sum_even3

def luhn_even(a,b):
c = a + b
return c

def luhn_final(f,g):
u = f + g
return u

for i in range(x,y):
v = luhn_odd(i)
w = luhn_even1(i)
z = luhn_even2(i)
l = luhn_even(w,z)
u = luhn_final(v,l)
if (u%10 == 0):
    print(i)
```

So basically I broke down the luhn algorithm into certain functions since it'd be really hard
to keep up with what's happening if all placed inside one singular source file. The problem arises in the luhn_even2 function, and can confirm all the other functions work, but for some reason this function won't return what's intended. If I nest if statements and for loops, I get a local error suggesting that a variable isn't local to its scope even though it's already initialized within the function. Can someone tell me what's going on? P.S. When running the code, it seems to print both valid and invalid numbers so something's not adding up.